# Running python code on local machine vs remote amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, keras, remote-access, putty

I am a bit new to python programming so excuse me for my ignorance. 
Please help as I have been at this for hours now and can't think of the answer.
All training & test data can be seen here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XaFM8BJFligrqeQdE-_5Id0V_SubJAZe

I have the following code which runs fine if I run it.

```
# Importing the Keras libraries and packages
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dense
# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())
# Step 4 - Full connection
classifier.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.2,
zoom_range = 0.2,
horizontal_flip = True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/training_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('dataset/test_set',
target_size = (64, 64),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode = 'binary')
classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
steps_per_epoch = 8000,
epochs = 25,
validation_data = test_set,
validation_steps = 2000)
# Part 3 - Making new predictions
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
test_image = image.load_img('dataset/single_prediction/cat_or_dog_1.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction = 'dog'
else:
    prediction = 'cat'
```

However I have tried to run this on my EC2 instance by using putty to remotely access UBUNTU.  When I run it, I get errors like this

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 10, in <module>
    classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
```

I was able to fix this particular error by changing  Steps 1 & 2 slightly by changing the Conv2D function inputs. They now look like this.

```
# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape = (64, 64, 3), activation = 'relu'))   
# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, activation = 'relu'))
```

But now I am getting a separate error that says:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so.7.5 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:128] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so.7.5 locally
Found 2516 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 2023 images belonging to 2 classes.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 47, in <module>
    callbacks=None,verbose=1)
TypeError: fit_generator() takes at least 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Why am I getting all these errors? I don't think I am supposed to keep looking up how to fix individual errors. I think it might have to do with different versions of python and libraries being used.  On my machine I have keras 2.1 and python 3.6.  On remote access, I have keras 1.2 and python 2.7.  When I try to update via

```
 pip install --upgrade keras
```

or
     python -m pip install --upgrade keras

It gives the following

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 303, in move
    os.unlink(src)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/bin/f2py'
```

Comment: Are you using the same versions of Python and all the relevant libraries? This seems like the kind of error you'd get from moving from version 1.3 to version 2.0 of some library that changed its API in a backward-incompatible way. When that happens, there's usually documentation explaining how to adapt your code to the new API (which you might have to follow in reverse if you're going from 2.0 to 1.3). Or, of course, you can just use the same version on both computers.

Comment: I suspected this was the issue but I wasn't fully sure. Is there a way to update what is on the remote server?

Comment: The first step is to find out _what_ versions are installed on each side. From your terminal, run `pip list`, then filter the result down to the ones that (a) are different and (b) look like they might conceivably be relevant, and add the result to your question.

Comment: Thanks but still having issues see edit

Comment: Of course you're still having issues. Just diagnosing where the problem comes from doesn't magically solve it.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get what you mean. The problem is the different versions and so I tried to update keras and python and am still getting errors. I might just look at the older documentation and change my work accordingly but I want to know if there is a way to update the files I have remotely or not. I apologize if I am asking a stupid question

Comment: You almost certainly want to use Python 3. You may already have Python 3; if not, it’s not a matter of upgrading Python from 2.7 to 3.6, but installing 3.6 alongside 2.7. Either way, you’ll probably have to use `python3` and `pip3` commands. Learning and using `virtualenv` will probably make your life easier. Anyway, after all that, you should be able to install up-to-date versions of Keras and it’s dependencies for Python 3. (You might want to use the exact same versions instead of just whatever’s newest.) This is a lot to fit in a comment, which is why I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're using radically different versions of everything.

As a general rule, most libraries change major versions for incompatible API changes, so you should expect Keras 2.1 to be incompatible with code written for Keras 1.2, and vice-versa. There may be documentation that explains how to port Keras 1 code to Keras 2, which you could follow in reverse to backport your Keras 2 code to Keras 1, but you'd have to do the same thing for any other such libraries—and for Python itself. And then you'd have to maintain the two different versions in parallel, which is never fun.

Just doing `pip install --upgrade keras` isn't going to fix that. It's going to try to install the latest version of Keras available for Python 2, which may not be the same as the latest version available for Python 3. (Many libraries are dropping support for Python 2 going forward, and only providing minor bug fixes for old versions.)

So, you first need to install Python 3 on your Amazon instance.

In fact, you may already have it under the name `python3` instead of `python`. In which case you should already be able to just use `pip3`.

If not, you need to use your package manager to install Python 3, and *then* you should be able to use `pip3`.

Meanwhile, if you're trying to install packages into the system Python site-packages on most linux setups, you need to use `sudo`. You might be happier using a user site-packages directory, but using `virtualenv` and installing just into that environment is even nicer. Explaining how to use `virtualenv` is way too much to put into a paragraph of a larger SO answer, but [the docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/) include a pretty nice tutorial.